# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /home/u655787642/public_html/index.php on line 40

Tags: php, mysqli

I've done some research into this but simply cannot figure out how to do this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

This is what I use to retrieve the data from the database, and I read I should use fetch to make it work.

I'd like to insert the retrieved data into a table with this code:

```
<?php foreach($result as $tr) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$tr['t_Naam']?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `$conn->query` execute query you need to use `fetch_array` for getting data

Comment: You ran the query, but you do not fetch the results. Instead you try to output a result resource, which does not really make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$conn->query` execute query you need to use `fetch_array` for getting data.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($tr = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $tr['t_Naam'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

For more [information](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

The mysqli_query() returns an object not array:

```
while ($tr = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $tr['t_Naam']."<br>";
}
```